# How to convert pubsub payload to LogEntry object in log export

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I have enabled log exports to a pub sub topic. I am using dataflow to process these logs and store relevant columns in BigQuery. Can someone please help with the conversion of the pubsub message payload to a `LogEntry` object.
I have tried the following code:

```
@ProcessElement
public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception {
    PubsubMessage pubsubMessage = c.element();

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    byte[] payload = pubsubMessage.getPayload();
    String s = new String(payload, "UTF8");
    LogEntry logEntry = mapper.readValue(s, LogEntry.class);
}
```

But I got the following error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not find a (Map) Key deserializer for type [simple type, class com.google.protobuf.Descriptors$FieldDescriptor]
```

Edit:
I tried the following code:

```
try {
        ByteArrayInputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.decodeBase64(pubsubMessage.getPayload()));
        LogEntry logEntry = LogEntry.parseDelimitedFrom(stream);
        System.out.println("Log Entry = " + logEntry);
    } catch (InvalidProtocolBufferException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But I get the following error now:

`com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message end-group tag did not match expected tag`

Answer (score 0):

The [JSON format parser](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/java/util/src/main/java/com/google/protobuf/util/JsonFormat.java) should be able to do this. Java's not my strength, but I think you're looking for something like:

```
@ProcessElement
public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception {
  LogEntry.Builder entryBuilder = LogEntry.newBuilder();
  JsonFormat.Parser.usingTypeRegistry(
      JsonFormat.TypeRegistry.newBuilder()
          .add(LogEntry.getDescriptor())
          .build())
      .ignoringUnknownFields()
      .merge(c.element(), entryBuilder);
  LogEntry entry = entryBuilder.build();
  ...
}
```

You might be able to get away without registering the type. I think in C++ the proto types are linked into a global registry.

You'll want "ignoringUnknownFields" in case the service adds new fields and exports them and you haven't updated your copy of the proto descriptor. Any "@type" fields in the exported JSON that will cause problems too.

You may need special handling of the payload (i.e. strip if from the JSON and then parse it separately). If it's JSON I'd expect the parser to try populating sub-messages that don't exist. If it's proto ... it actually might work if you register the [Any](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#any) type too.